# while running YOLO for test custom object cfg file path error the path is correct but even though its showing this error

Tags: python, yolo, darkflow

This code is for running my trained weights the folder ckpt contains 1050 step train data and this file is in outside of cfg folder in darkflow main folder.

`import cv2`
`from darkflow.net.build import TFNet`
`import numpy as np`
`import time`

`options = {
    'model': 'cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg',
    'load': 1050,
    'threshold': 0.2,
    'gpu': 1.0
}`

after running this code in atom editor below error showing
`Parsing cfg//tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\amard\Desktop\Hotel\darkflow\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    tfnet = TFNet(options)

  File "C:\Users\amard\Desktop\Hotel\darkflow\darkflow\net\build.py", line 58, in __init__

    darknet = Darknet(FLAGS)
  File "C:\Users\amard\Desktop\Hotel\darkflow\darkflow\dark\darknet.py", line 17, in __init__

    src_parsed = self.parse_cfg(self.src_cfg, FLAGS)

  File "C:\Users\amard\Desktop\Hotel\darkflow\darkflow\dark\darknet.py", line 68, in parse_cfg

    for i, info in enumerate(cfg_layers):

  File "C:\Users\amard\Desktop\Hotel\darkflow\darkflow\utils\process.py", line 66, in cfg_yielder

    layers, meta = parser(model); yield meta;
  File "C:\Users\amard\Desktop\Hotel\darkflow\darkflow\utils\process.py", line 17, in parser

    with open(model, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cfg//tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg'

[Finished in 4.298s]`

Comment: Try to change ''cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg'' to 'cfg\tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg'.

Answer (score 0):

Oftenly I was also used  get something similar to this error

my first mistake was not to open Jupyter notebook at the directory where I kept these folders
so, try to open the notebook from that directory

(in windows simply type cmd on location bar of shift+right-click)

(in MacOS there is some setting first enable that then right-click on the folder)

later I used this options

```
options={
    'model':'cfg/yolo.cfg',
    'load':'bin/yolov2.weights',
    'threshold':0.3,
    'gpu':1.0
}
```

tfNet=TFNet(options)

and everything work as expected

hope this will help you